# Can I get the Morticulturalist achievement if I sell plants from my Zen Garden?

Tags: steam, achievements, plants-vs-zombies

I'm trying to get [the Morticulturalist achievement](http://plantsvszombies.wikia.com/wiki/Morticulturalist) in Plants vs Zombies: Game of the Year edition on Steam and I have filled all of the slots in both my Day and Night time Zen Garden, however, I am still far from getting this achievement.

My question is this: If I sell some of the duplicate plants from these Zen Gardens to make room for the ones that I'm still missing, will I still receive the achievement?

Comment: I'm confused.  I thought this achievement was by making all the plant types available for gameplay...not for collecting them in the zen garden.

Comment: Wow, I didn't even notice that that was what the achievement was referring to.  I suppose that since I purchased all of the bonus plants from Crazy Dave while in Offline Mode that Steam ignored me getting that achievement.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Beska's comment is correct, this achievement has nothing to do with the Zen Garden, it is for "unlocking" all the plants to be usable in game.  Many of the plants are earned by beating levels, the rest are purchased from Crazy Dave.